# Django model override save() method raises error when calling super()

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-users

I have the following Django model:

```
class TCDUser(AbstractUser):
    is_change_password = models.BooleanField(_("Cambiar Password?"), default=True)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, default=[], related_name='users', verbose_name=_("Grupos"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Usuario")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Usuarios")

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}]{}".format(self.pk, self.username)

    def save(self):
        create = True if self.id is None else False

        if create:
            self.set_password(self.password)

        super(CustomModel).save()
```

And this is the serializer:

```
class TCDUserSerializer(CustomModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TCDUser
        fields = ('id','username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'password', 'is_change_password', 'groups')
```

When I send a POST to the regular DRF ModelViewSet, I get this exception:

```
TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `TCDUser.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `TCDUser.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the TCDUserSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
...
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'
```

If I remove the call `super(CustomModel).save()`, the exception is no more, but I need to set the password when the user is created.

Answer (score 0):

- you should call `super(TCDUser, self).save()` instead of `super(CustomModel).save()`
- the error `TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'`
  is self-explanatory, you should also pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to overridden method `save()`.

```
class TCDUser(AbstractUser):

    [..]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # -- HERE --
        create = True if self.id is None else False

        if create:
            self.set_password(self.password)

        super(TCDUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # -- HERE --
```

Comment: Nope, same exception.